# Cordova - Android. Build Failed

Tags: android, cordova

I'm creating an app using cordova. I've just created the iOS version, and everything works fine (the app is waiting for review on the app store). 
The problem is with the android version. If i use the `cordova build android` in the CLI i get this: (verbose version of the android build) http://pastebin.com/gtEMKAFB and I haven't the android version yet.
I haven't found a solution since like (maybe) 1 month or more. 
Please help, thank you!

Comment: have you tried to build the simple hellocordova project to check if the problem comes from your app or from your build environment?

Comment: I've just tried, and i can deploy the helloworld app to the emulator. So I don't have any build environment problems.It seems that i have some problems with my app's files. But this is strange (i think) because everything works fine for the iOS version!

Comment: If it doesn't build, it seems it's something to do with java files. Have you developped some plugins? Or maybe are you using some plugins that have issue with android. To investigate, you could import the project into eclipse and see if it finds some compilations issues (you'll see the details in the problems tab).

Comment: Or maybe you added the android platform to your project with an older version of cordova (cordova 3.0 or 3.1 for example) and have upgraded to 3.2 or > and forgot to upgrade the android platform (cordova 3.2+ doesn't have a jar anymore but the lib in a separate project)